# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #16: Reverse Puzzling

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the sixteenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2841/5373), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373). This fortnight's topic is [reverse-puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-puzzling) (suggested by [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino)), and will span from the **19th of September to the 2nd of October**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23") Fortnightly Topics.*

Comment: Let's make the next challenge `reverse-reverse-puzzling`. Oh! wait.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[reverse-puzzling]%20created%3a2016-09-19..2016-10-02%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #16:**

- [Cheating is efficient, but only until you get caught!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42813/cheating-is-efficient-but-only-until-you-get-caught) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)
- [Reverse puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42814/reverse-puzzling) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)
- [Highlighter traces on a sheet of paper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42879/highlighter-traces-on-a-sheet-of-paper) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)
- [The wrong solution?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42914/the-wrong-solution) by [Wu33o](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20690/wu33o)
- [My colleague got mad!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42919/my-colleague-got-mad) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957/iaminpls)
- [What kind of puzzle is solved by these sequences of numbers?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42926/what-kind-of-puzzle-is-solved-by-these-sequences-of-numbers) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [Can you steal the show?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42950/can-you-steal-the-show) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil)
- [The Mystery of the MathJax Lines](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/the-mystery-of-the-mathjax-lines) by [humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn)
- [My colleague's search history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43028/my-colleagues-search-history) by [ConMan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23445/conman)
- [What are they trying to solve?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43033/what-are-they-trying-to-solve) by [Marius](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19989/marius)
- [What are Jim and Bob trying to solve?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43041/what-are-jim-and-bob-trying-to-solve) by [Jamal Senjaya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756/jamal-senjaya)
- [Five Closely Related Puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43054/five-closely-related-puzzles) by [hexomino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18422/hexomino)
- [Reassemble the riddles!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43085/reassemble-the-riddles) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)
- [Hazing the new guy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43088/hazing-the-new-guy) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [The outset of the edge of cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43093) by [TheBitByte](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29958/thebitbyte)
- [A Modular History Lesson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43364/a-modular-history-lesson) by [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5297/sconibulus)
- [A colleague's note](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43459/a-colleagues-note) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)
- [Jim is trying to prove he has solved the puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43469/jim-is-trying-to-prove-he-has-solved-the-puzzle) by [Jamal Senjaya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756/jamal-senjaya)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Reassemble the riddles!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43085/reassemble-the-riddles) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor), with a score of **29** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is either [What are they trying to solve?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43033/what-are-they-trying-to-solve) by [Marius](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19989/marius) or [A colleague's note](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43459/a-colleagues-note) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva), each with approximately **1000** views during the fortnight.