# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #17: Board Games

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the seventeenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2841/5373), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373). This fortnight's topic is [board-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-games) (suggested by [Emrakul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20/emrakul)), and will span from the **3rd of October to the 16th of October**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23") Fortnightly Topics.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[board-games]%20created%3a2016-10-03..2016-10-16%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #17:**

- [Closed knight tour on 7x7 board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/closed-knight-tour-on-7x7-board) by [Jamal Senjaya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756/jamal-senjaya)
- [Monte Carlo Chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43771) by [Mike Earnest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10615)
- [Customers are weird these days](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43868) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Capturing The Shadow King](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44011/capturing-the-shadow-king) by [TSLF](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30856/tslf)
- [8-queen puzzle on its head](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44085/8-queen-puzzle-on-its-head) by [Garrison Pendergrass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30850/garrison-pendergrass)
- [The Swedish king and the chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44109/the-swedish-king-and-the-chessboard) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [A Boyfriend's Mysterious Message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44137) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421)
- [Hnefatafl - a lost Art](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/hnefatafl-a-lost-art) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250)
- [A game of Connect 4++](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44207) by [Kruga](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19103)
- [Chess puzzle in which guarded pieces may not move](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44278/chess-puzzle-in-which-guarded-pieces-may-not-move) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [Help Black slide the blocks to solve this chess problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44293/help-black-slide-the-blocks-to-solve-this-chess-problem) by [Rosie F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22922)
- [Cover an unusual board with minimum chess rooks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44363) by [Jamal Senjaya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756/jamal-senjaya)
- [Checkmate all the kings #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44388) by [Lord of dark](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20274)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [A Boyfriend's Mysterious Message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44137) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421), with a score of **28** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [A Boyfriend's Mysterious Message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44137) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421), with approximately **3190** views during the fortnight.

Comment: Should the "winners" be decided at the end of the fortnight? Perhaps a fortnight after would be better - often times the best puzzles take a while to make, hence appear later; furthermore I believe that many voters hold back on up voting a question until there is a solution that satisfies them that the puzzle was indeed a good one.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's true, but on the other hand there's *always* going to be a slight advantage in favour of earlier puzzles, which wouldn't entirely be got rid of by shifting the 'deadline' forwards. And for the last several topic challenges I've been calculating the 'winners' at the end of the fortnight; it would be very hard to recalc those now. Besides, it's just a bit of fun - there are no actual prizes for the winners or anything :-)