# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #18: Mechanical Puzzles

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the eighteenth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2841/5373), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373). This fortnight's topic is [mechanical-puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-puzzles) (suggested by [Emrakul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20)), and will span from the **17th of October to the 30th of October**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23") Fortnightly Topics.*

Comment: We should start using these challenges as a time to improve the tag wiki for the highlighted topic.  For example, `mechanical-puzzles` currently seems to suggest it only includes things like Rubik's cubes and sliding puzzles.  I'm not familiar enough with the tag, but looking through the questions with the tag suggest some other types can also fit in.

Comment: Wikipedia defines mechanical puzzles as all all puzzles involving the manipulation of physical objects, assembling, disassembling, untangling, trick objects, where you need to find how to reach a specific goal.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_puzzle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[mechanical-puzzles]%20created%3a2016-10-17..2016-10-30%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #18:**

- [A weird deleted Puzzling.SE question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44854/a-weird-deleted-puzzling-se-questio) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478)
- [Need help solving 3d wooden cross puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45046) by [Yury Fedorov](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31493)
- [Puzzle similar to 15-puzzle but more moveable pieces?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45064) by [errantlinguist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31502)
- [halloween.zip file](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45108) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Four flipped edges in the equator layer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45126) by [Evil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18569)
- [Magnetic Rubik's cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45163) by [TSLF](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30856)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [A weird deleted Puzzling.SE question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44854/a-weird-deleted-puzzling-se-questio) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478), with a score of **40** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is either [Puzzle similar to 15-puzzle but more moveable pieces?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45064) by [errantlinguist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31502) or [A weird deleted Puzzling.SE question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44854/a-weird-deleted-puzzling-se-questio) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478), both with approximately **940** views during the fortnight.

Comment: Congrats, Lukas! :-)