# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #19: Unconventional Tag Fusion

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the nineteenth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2841/5373), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373). This fortnight's topic is "***Unconventional Tag Fusion***" (suggested by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)), and will span from the **31st of October to the 13th of November**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions that use two or more tags not normally seen together (more detail below) and post it as an answer to this question.

---

**Note:** This is a little different from the usual single tag challenges. Your goal is to use *two tags which would not normally be seen together* on a single puzzle. It's up to individual users to decide if their chosen tags are "unconventional" enough, however, the intent of the challenge is that the two tags should *seem like an unlikely pairing to a casual reader*.

In other words, whilst you may like to draw inspiration from [tags which are rarely paired](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/546243/unconventional-tag-fusion), having few existing tagged puzzles isn't necessarily in the spirit of the challenge.

For example, a pairing of [no-computers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-computers) and [wordplay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordplay) isn't really going to surprise anyone so shouldn't be considered "unconventional", even though there are currently no puzzles tagged that way. Better examples might include (but are certainly not limited to):

- [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus)+[chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)
- [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle)+[rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube)
- [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)+[cryptic-clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues)
- [music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)+[calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle)

Ideally, puzzles should involve the two tags being genuinely merged into a single challenge, rather than just having a two step process of, applying tag A then tag B.

---

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3292/5373)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23") Fortnightly Topics.*

Comment: **Note to participants: Please edit your own puzzles into the community wiki answer below**. Unlike other fortnightly challenges, it will be difficult to tell if something is meant to be part of the challenge or not, so others won't be able to edit it in on your behalf as easily.

Comment: Creative idea! ...

Comment: This was an excellent challenge.  I would not be opposed to having another one like this some day.

Comment: @DavidStarkey - Agreed. I think it went really well. Lots of awesomely creative puzzles across the board. Thanks to all involved!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**List of questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #19:**

- [A weird and spooky clock](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45186) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478) ([cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher) + [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry))
- [A crossword so simple, it practically solves itself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45191) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208) ([crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords)+[logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction))
- [Simply Riddleculous](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45198/simply-riddleculous) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil) ([riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) + [number-sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-sequence))
- [Trick or Treating in Trutham-And-Ly](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45210/trick-or-treating-in-trutham-and-ly) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio) ([logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid) + [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars))
- [**Implication is the key**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45225/implication-is-the-key) by [The Great Duck](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21905/thegreatduck) ([geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)+[treasure-hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure-hunt))
- [RIDDÅL - another unfinished flat-pack puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45269/ridd%C3%85l-another-unfinished-flat-pack-puzzle) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack) ([mechanical-puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-puzzles)+[riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle))
- [A Simple Chess Rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/a-simple-chess-rebus) by [Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31484/silenus) ([chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)+[rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus))
- [Yet Another Simple Chess Rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45276/yet-another-simple-chess-rebus) by [AeJay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2730/aejey) ([chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)+[rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus))
- [Rhyme of the century!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45312/rhyme-of-the-century) by [Techidiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30887/techidiot) ([lateral-thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking)+[steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography))
- [Which word wasn't with Wednesday's ...crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45316/which-word-wasnt-with-wednesdays-crossword) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey) ([crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crosswords)+[odd-one-out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/odd-one-out))
- [Rubik's Chess Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45372/rubiks-chess-puzzle) by [Artur Kirkoryan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14140/artur-kirkoryan) ([chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)+[rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube))
- [Vacation at P.U.Z.Z.L.E](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45424/15632) by [Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar) ([language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)+[visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual))
- [The Prognosticator](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45430) by [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5297) ([computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle)+[logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction))
- [Discovering the past](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45470/19766) by [Alenanno](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19766/alenanno) ([treasure-hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure-hunt)+[password](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password))
- [Music-Related Rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45542/music-related-rebus-puzzle) by [Margalo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30434/margalo) ([music](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)+[rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus))
- [Sudoku as Poetry: A Tag-Fusion Masterpiece](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45548) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421) ([sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku)+[poetry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry))
- [A 16 Clue Sudoku Puzzle (but the kings can't be in check)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45551) by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208) ([sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku)+[chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess))

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[A crossword so simple, it practically solves itself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45191)* by *[Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208)*, with a score of **34** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is *[A crossword so simple, it practically solves itself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45191)* by *[Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208)*, with approximately **4000** views during the fortnight.