# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the seventh installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-eigth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Unusual tag mix"*** (suggested by [melfnt](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63414)) and will span from the **24th of January to the 6th of February**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Unusual tag mix
>
> I like puzzles that mix very different topics and solution methods, even completely unrelated to each other. So my proposal for this challenge is simple: pick any two (or more) tags that are unlikely to be seen together and create a puzzle.
>
> Some of my favorite mixes:
>
> - [R.H.P.C. crossword puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67478/r-h-p-c-crossword-puzzle)
> - [Japanese Fusion Alphabet Soup](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58194/japanese-fusion-alphabet-soup)
> - [I'm largest when I'm five, what am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89743/im-largest-when-im-five-what-am-i)
>
> To help you with choosing the tags, I set up [this query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/edit/1340981#resultSets) that selects the unused pairs of tags considering only [the top 30 tags on PSE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) (i.e. for each line of the query results there is no question tagged with both [tag1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag1) and [tag2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag2)). Here is a snapshot of the results as of 2020-12-08, re-run the query at any time to check if something changed:
>
> | tag1 | tag2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | calculation-puzzle | cryptic-clues |
> | calculation-puzzle | geography |
> | calculation-puzzle | rebus |
> | calculation-puzzle | steganography |
> | chess | computer-puzzle |
> | chess | english |
> | chess | language |
> | chess | pattern |
> | chess | word-property |
> | combinatorics | cipher |
> | combinatorics | cryptic-clues |
> | combinatorics | english |
> | combinatorics | geography |
> | combinatorics | language |
> | combinatorics | rebus |
> | combinatorics | rhyme |
> | combinatorics | steganography |
> | combinatorics | word-property |
> | cryptic-clues | word-property |
> | geometry | cryptic-clues |
> | geometry | english |
> | geometry | language |
> | geometry | rebus |
> | geometry | wordplay |
> | optimization | cipher |
> | optimization | cryptic-clues |
> | optimization | geography |
> | optimization | language |
> | optimization | rebus |
> | optimization | rhyme |
> | optimization | steganography |
> | optimization | wordplay |
> | optimization | word-property |
> | rebus | word-property |
> | rhyme | word-property |
> | riddle | optimization |
> | strategy | cryptic-clues |
> | strategy | english |
> | strategy | language |
> | strategy | rebus |
> | strategy | rhyme |
> | strategy | riddle |
> | strategy | steganography |
> | strategy | word |
> | strategy | wordplay |
> | strategy | word-property |

Comment: I am not able to re-run the query to get the updated results: I always get the same results even if I use [some trick to disable the SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325802/data-explorer-cache) cache. Any help?

Comment: Does a question still apply for this FTC if a tag combo is previously unused even if the way it combines the tags isn't particularly creative? (ie. a puzzle type, like word-sequence, and a knowledge type, like music, where a list of songs would reveal a property)

Comment: @samm82 yes, the only constraints for this challenge are the used tags

Comment: I just realized there was a challenge with the same topic in 2016: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion/5615#5615

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48:**

- [A Cryptic Property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106863) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054)
- [O Cryptic! My Cryptic!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106904) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Cryptic Geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106930) by [GrimGrom](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31484/)
- [Scrabblescrapers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106987) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [An Anagram Tribond: You can love it, or not](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107015) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054)
- [Mathematics for the English major](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107019) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [What is a Prebus Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107036) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644)
- [Earth Science | Chemistry + Flags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107039) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054)
- [An Anime Affix Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107069) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054)
- [A Cryptic Cryptarithm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107103) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054)
- [Slitherlink with a message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107123) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [What is a Prebus Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107036) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with a score of **21** at the end of the fortnight.
- [O Cryptic! My Cryptic!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106904) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217), with a score of **19** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Earth Science | Chemistry + Flags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107039) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054), with a score of **14** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [What is a Prebus Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107036) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644), with **928** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [An Anagram Tribond: You can love it, or not](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107015) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054), with **381** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Earth Science | Chemistry + Flags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107039) by [samm82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50054), with **321** views at the end of the fortnight.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the mentioned pairs of tags were used during the challenge. Here are the remaining ones as of 2021-02-01 (for each line of the table, there is still no question tagged with both tag1 and tag2):

> | tag1 | tag2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | calculation-puzzle | geography |
> | calculation-puzzle | rebus |
> | calculation-puzzle | steganography |
> | chess | computer-puzzle |
> | chess | english |
> | chess | language |
> | chess | pattern |
> | chess | word-property |
> | combinatorics | cipher |
> | combinatorics | cryptic-clues |
> | combinatorics | geography |
> | combinatorics | language |
> | combinatorics | rebus |
> | combinatorics | rhyme |
> | combinatorics | steganography |
> | combinatorics | word-property |
> | geometry | english |
> | geometry | language |
> | geometry | rebus |
> | geometry | wordplay |
> | optimization | cipher |
> | optimization | cryptic-clues |
> | optimization | geography |
> | optimization | language |
> | optimization | rebus |
> | optimization | rhyme |
> | optimization | steganography |
> | optimization | wordplay |
> | optimization | word-property |
> | rhyme | word-property |
> | riddle | optimization |
> | strategy | cryptic-clues |
> | strategy | english |
> | strategy | language |
> | strategy | rebus |
> | strategy | rhyme |
> | strategy | riddle |
> | strategy | steganography |
> | strategy | word |
> | strategy | wordplay |
> | strategy | word-property |

And here are the ruled out pairs:

> | tag1 | tag2 | ruled out by |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | <s>cryptic-clues</s> | <s>word-property</s> | [A Cryptic Property](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106863/a-cryptic-property) |
> | <s>geometry</s> | <s>cryptic-clues</s> | [Cryptic Geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106930/cryptic-geometry) |
> | <s>combinatorics</s> | <s>english</s> | [Mathematics for the English major](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107019/mathematics-for-the-english-major) |
> | <s>rebus</s> | <s>word-property</s> | [What is a Prebus Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107036/what-is-a-prebus-word) |
> | <s>calculation-puzzle</s> | <s>cryptic-clues</s> | [A Cryptic Cryptarithm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107103/a-cryptic-cryptarithm) |