# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #20: Pattern

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twentieth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [pattern](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern) (suggested by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)), and will span from the the **14th of November to the 27th of November**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23") Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Answer (score 6):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[pattern]%20created%3a2016-11-14..2016-11-27%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #20:**

- [What is a VP Number™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45644/what-is-an-vp-number) by [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009/sid)
- [Where is it moving, all around the world?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45659/5373) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [Numbers at a flower-like circles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45661/numbers-at-a-flower-like-circles) by [Jamal Senjaya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756/jamal-senjaya)
- [What is a Reciprocal Word?™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45690/5373) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655/levieux)
- [Can you save my friends and me?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45703/can-you-save-my-friends-and-i) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957/iaminpls)
- [What is a CPO Word?™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45708/5373) by [Matt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20151/matt)
- [Don't clear your terminal history 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45716/dont-clear-your-terminal-history-3) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [Aptitude Assessment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45720/aptitude-assessment) by [Phlarx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29647/phlarx)
- [What is a Trending Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45740/5373) by [Jezzamon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9046/jezzamon)
- [Three elementary number sequences](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45793/5373) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655/levieux)
- [Find the missing result](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45822/5373) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655/levieux)
- [The Pattern-Bot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45866/the-pattern-bot) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)
- [A strange series of words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45884/a-strange-series-of-words) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)
- [Find the secret word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45893/5373) by [stack reader](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30804/stack-reader)
- [A Cleverly Disguised Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45912) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421)
- [What is an Absolute Word?™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5373) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655/levieux)
- [What is a Frightful Number™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45981/5373) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)
- [A weird screensaver](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46019) by [Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14478)
- [A cubic colored pyramid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46050/19766) by [Alenanno](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19766)
- [Rendez-vous with your eccentric uncle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46089) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655)
- [Old Indian Artwork](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46096) by [TSLF](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30856)
- [What is a Flawless Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46148) by [Oray](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18514)
- [What is a Stable Word™?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46161) by [Borka223](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/26067)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Find the missing result](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45822) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655), with a score of **20** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [Find the secret word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45893) by [stack reader](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30804), with approximately **1000** views during the fortnight.