# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #21: Geography

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-first instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [geography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)(suggested by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)), and will span from the the **28th of November to the 11th of December**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[geography]%20created%3a2016-11-28..2016-12-11%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #21:**

- [Don't clear your terminal history 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46184) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Avast ye puzzlers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46220) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Help me find my missing friend!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46221) by [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421)
- [Let's hope there will be snow!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46407) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957)
- [A pilot's messages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46410) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655)
- [Is humanity truly doomed?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46529/5373) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [Which countries are these, and who's the missing man?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46599) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [A pilot's messages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46410) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655), with a score of **46** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [A pilot's messages](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46410) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655), with approximately **3800** views during the fortnight.