# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #22: Animals

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-second instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [animals](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals)(suggested by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135)), and will span from the the **12th of December to the 25th of December**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Comment: Gosh darn it you're fast.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? ...weird. Are people over fortnightly challenges or something, or just unhappy that "animals" is the topic?

Comment: @Alconja Didn't downvote, but maybe they disagree with the creation of the `animals` tag just for this challenge?  Whether or not it is a good tag should be discussed in it's own meta post, though.

Comment: Sorry to intrude, but would my puzzle be considered acceptable for this challenge? I never participated before so I am not sure how to proceed... http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46874/my-friend-is-quite-silly

Comment: @stackreader As long as it fits the tag description, it's also acceptable for this challenge. You can A) Wait until someone adds it (usually happens very soon, except when it's UTC night), or B) Add it yourself in the given format. In this case someone already added your entry by now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[animals]%20created%3a2016-12-12..2016-12-25%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #22:**

- [An animal out of matchsticks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46614) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957)
- [The Baffling Birdcage](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46625) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)
- [Birdies and Tigers and Bears, Oh My!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46653) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633)
- [What is the world?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46670) by [Volatility](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8949)
- [Don't duck this story!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46685) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957)
- [The ravens of peacocks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46687) by [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5297)
- [What is a Cardinal Animal?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46707) by [Zymurge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31511)
- [Triptych of Animal Cryptics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46710) by [Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31484)
- [A mysterious email from the World Wildlife Fund](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46726) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [A Day at the Zoo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46731) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [A bizarre slot machine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46736) by [RottersSlave](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32660)
- [Plenty of Clues in the Crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46740) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)
- [Hickory Dickory dock](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46750) by [Jamal Senjaya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756)
- [My friend is quite silly](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46874) by [stack reader](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30804)
- [A birdwatching trip?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46902) by [whrrgarbl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23421)
- [Four Birds + One](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47095) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [An animal out of matchsticks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46614) by [IAmInPLS](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25957), with a score of **26** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [My friend is quite silly](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46874) by [stack reader](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30804), with approximately **1800** views during the fortnight