# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #23: Seasonal

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-third instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [seasonal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasonal)(suggested by [A E](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4050)), and will span from the the **26th of December to the 8th of January**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

Subjects could include:

- Boxing Day
- Christmas
- Epiphany
- Feast of Winter Veil
- Festivus
- Hannukah
- Kwanzaa
- New Year's Eve and New Year's Day, Hogmanay
- Newtonmas
- Pancha Ganapati
- Saturnalia
- Twelfth Night
- Stack Exchange Winter Bash
- Winter Solstice
- Winterval
- Yalda
- Yule

and any other real or fictional seasonal festivities which puzzling.SE members wish to mark.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bseasonal%5D+created%3A2016-12-26..2017-01-08+is%3Aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #23:**

- [The best season of all](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47175) by [stack reader](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30804)
- [Santa's Sacks and the Puzzling Presents](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47194) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)
- [A Christmas Tale for 12](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47210) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Eight students in a line](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47236) by [Wen1now](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32642)
- [Putting up the lights](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47266) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Putting up the lights two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47291) by [Wen1now](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32642)
- [My Uncle's present](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47299) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250)
- [Post-Christmas - Christmas Movie Rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47327) by [Arth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17890)
- [The Revenge of the Post-Christmas - Christmas Movie Rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47333) by [Arth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17890)
- [Christmas light horror story!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47368) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)
- [A quick, easy mistyped question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47402/a-quick-easy-mistyped-question) by [Wen1now](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32642)
- [Time for Something New](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47408/5373) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)
- [Puzzling SE in 2017](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47426/5373) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [Measurements for 2017](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47486/5373) by [histocrat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9523/histocrat)
- [Happy 2017 Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47655/happy-2017-sudoku) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050/maria-deleva)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [A quick, easy mistyped question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47402) by [Wen1now](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32642), with a score of **30** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [My Uncle's present](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47299) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250), with approximately **1100** views during the fortnight.