# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #24: Grid-Deduction

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-fourth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/). This fortnight's topic is [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction)(suggested by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)), and will span from the the **9th of January to the 22nd of January**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgrid-deduction%5D+created%3A2017-01-09..2017-01-22+is%3Aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #24:**

- [Question 16 Ripple Effect](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47718) by [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876)
- [Introducing: Number Slope™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47723) by [Volatility](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8949)
- [Spell out your moves and reach the exit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47741) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [Wumpus-hunting Masyu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47792) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071)
- [A "Letter" Slope puzzle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47815) by [Volatility](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8949)
- [WITLESS - A Puzzling Journey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47870) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)
- [Jon Mark Perry's Grid Logic Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47925) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [The Peculiar File](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47956) by [dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22684)
- [A Trip to Ripple Islands](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47959) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)
- [Empty sudoku puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47987) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050)
- [Simple grid deduction puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48001) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050)
- [A Family Reunion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48009) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903)
- [Strategy for solving 0hh1 and Unruly?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48017) by [rand al'thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373)
- [HAISU (Room Count): An original grid-logic challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48029) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)
- [Sum in A Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48105) by [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009)
- [A Six-Faced Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48200) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596)
- [Time to Hit the Bricks!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48316) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Empty sudoku puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47987) by [Maria Deleva](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29050), with a score of **51** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [A Six-Faced Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48200) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596), with approximately **1800** views during the fortnight