# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #44: Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the third installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenges Rerun described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841) and the forty-fourth installment of the FTCs overall, with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032). This fortnight's topic is ***"Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community"*** (suggested by [Bubbler](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/71652)) and will span from the **29th of November to the 12th of December**. During this period, we will compile the list of relevant questions and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7032)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a%22Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
The suggestion is copied to this post for posterity.

> ### Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community
>
> We already had *two* Fortnights related to [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction): vanilla one as [#24](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5733/71652), and hybrids as [#32](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5998/71652). So this one will be the threrun in this topic. Then you ask, "Why the third time?"
>
> I enjoy grid deduction a lot, but the same genre posted over and over builds up a "genre fatigue". Recently I introduced two new types of grid deduction puzzles:
>
> - [Trichain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/102673/71652), which I made up from scratch, and
> - [Heteromino](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/103997/71652), which I found by randomly browsing the Internet (googling the title gives very few results).
>
> There must be a reason to the fact that the two "introduction" puzzles are among the top 3 of all of my puzzles, and repeated posts of the same genre earn fewer and fewer upvotes, even though the quality gets better (at least IMO).
>
> Therefore, the challenge is as the title says: Introduce a *new* grid deduction genre to the community!
>
> **Rules:**
>
> - The genre must be unseen on Puzzling before the start of the Fortnight.
>
>   - **Exception:** a genre qualifies if it has only appeared as a part of a mashup puzzle of 3 genres or more. Icebarn qualifies because it has only appeared in [a connect wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104498/71652) and [a massive loop puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52899/71652), and Nurimaze qualifies because it has only appeared in [a massive "needs a name" puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/102465/71652).
> - Only one puzzle per user per genre qualifies. (This is to account for the possibility of multiple users working on the same new genre.)
> - For mashups of multiple genres, at least one of the genres must satisfy the above. An existing genre with extra rule(s) or mashups of existing genres do not qualify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**List of all questions published as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #44:**

- [Nurimisaki Puzzle: Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105251) by [Alaiko](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57098)
- [Tatamibari: an introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105257) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582)
- [Norinori: QR-Code-ish](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105267) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [Office Park: A Grid Deduction Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105279) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Dosun-Fuwari: an introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105286) by [melfnt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63414)
- [Palette: A Multicoloured Grid Deduction Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105306) by [Matthew Jensen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/62738)
- [Pentopia: One-way Crossing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105312) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [Hokuro Puzzle: Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105320) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396)
- [Sashigane: The Fives Have It](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105377) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582)
- [Greener Grasses: Around the Trees](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105391) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [Fighting Fish: An Aquarium-Star Battle Hybrid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105397) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69217)
- [Cross the Streams: Three?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105429) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- [Light and Shadow: Equal and Antisymmetric](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105430/57098) by [Alaiko](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57098)
- [Neighbors Grid Puzzle: A Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105537) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719)
- *add further entries in the form
  `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** three of these are:

- [Hokuro Puzzle: Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105320) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396), with a score of **25** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Norinori: QR-Code-ish](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105267) by [athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719), with a score of **16** at the end of the fortnight.
- [Nurimisaki Puzzle: Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105251) by [Alaiko](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57098), with a score of **15** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** three of these are:

- [Tatamibari: an introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105257) by [bobble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69582), with **782** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Hokuro Puzzle: Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105320) by [sarsaparilla](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60396), with **668** views at the end of the fortnight.
- [Nurimisaki Puzzle: Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105251) by [Alaiko](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57098), with **631** views at the end of the fortnight.

Comment: Wow, this really was athin's dream fortnight - 5 entries! (descending whistle)