# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #25: Wordplay

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-fifth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [wordplay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordplay)(suggested by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250)), and will span from the the **23rd of January to the 5th of February**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[wordplay]%20created%3a2017-01-23..2017-02-05%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #25:**

- [I never knew my words could speak!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/i-never-knew-my-words-could-speak) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)
- [Even odd words can be oddly even](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48438/even-odd-words-can-be-oddly-even) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [Unusually Cryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48477/unusually-cryptic) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper?tab=profile)
- [Perhaps A Human Is Not Quite Right](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48519/perhaps-a-human-is-not-quite-right) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper?tab=profile)
- [Metametacryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48530/metametacryptic) by [Silenus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31484/silenus?tab=profile)
- [Find the missing elements](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48535) by [Levieux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/31655)
- [Be careful with your words!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48569/be-careful-with-your-words) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)
- [Quotation Equation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48698/quotation-equation) by [Gordon K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14135/gordon-k)
- [Turning over a new page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48747/turning-over-a-new-page) by [Sp3000](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000)
- [Cryptic-ception](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48754/cryptic-ception) by [dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22684/dcfyj)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [I never knew my words could speak!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/i-never-knew-my-words-could-speak) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit), with a score of **30** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** of these is [Unusually Cryptic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48477/unusually-cryptic) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper), with approximately **2000** views during the fortnight.

The **most favorited** of these is [I never knew my words could speak!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/i-never-knew-my-words-could-speak) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit), with a favorite count of **3** at the end of the fortnight

The **average score** of these is approximately **11**.

The **average view count** of these is approximately **450**.

The **average favorite count** of these is **1.3**.