# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26: Rebus

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-sixth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [rebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebus)(suggested by [Mithrandir](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25966)), and will span from the the **6th of February to the 19th of February**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Comment: Yay! I can participate in this one.

Answer (score 4):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[rebus]%20created%3a2017-02-06..2017-02-19%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #26:**

- [A rebus from a while ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48831/) by [ConMan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23445/)
- [Rematry oshkabus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48889/rematry-oshkabus) by [Sp3000](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000)
- [GRID-THIRTY-SIX](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48948/grid-thirty-six) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper)
- [Four Fun-derful Rebuses](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48972/four-fun-derful-rebuses) by [Bailey M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11475/bailey-m)
- [Rad Enigma Based Upon Sketches](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/rad-enigma-based-upon-sketches) by [stacksfiller](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33827/stacksfiller)
- [Another attempt at movie rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48990/another-attempt-at-movie-rebus-puzzle) by [A J](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19658/a-j)
- [Which river is the treasure in?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49023/which-river-is-the-treasure-in/49026#49026) by [suomynonA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30865/suomynona)
- [Forget the freehand red circles - it's a freehand rebus! - Clue Twenty Eight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49079/forget-the-freehand-red-circles-its-a-freehand-rebus-clue-twenty-eight) by [Mithrandir](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25966/mithrandir)
- [Spot the Differebus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49101/spot-the-differebus) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [Eleanor's Emoji Story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49183/eleanors-emoji-story) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Rematry oshkabus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48889/rematry-oshkabus) by [Sp3000](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000), with a score of *23* at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [A rebus from a while ago](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48831/a-rebus-from-a-while-ago) by [ConMan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23445/conman), with approximately *1800* views during the fortnight.

The **most favorited** of these is [Rematry oshkabus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48889/rematry-oshkabus) by [Sp3000](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000), with a favorite count of **3** at the end of the fortnight

The **average score** of these is approximately **13**.

The **average view count** of these is approximately **470**.

The **average favorite count** of these is **0.7**.

Comment: I got a thing! I'd hoped to come up with a new puzzle too, but didn't get around to it.