# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #27: Treasure-Hunt

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-seventh instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [treasure-hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure-hunt) (suggested by user14478), and will span from the the **20th of February to the 5th of March**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[treasure-hunt]%20created%3a2017-02-20..2017-03-05%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #27:**

- [Journey to The Greatest Treasures of the Dungeons!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49309) by [Techidiot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30887)
- [Where is Steven the Stegosaurus?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49341) by [suomynonA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30865)
- [A Different Kind of Treasure Hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49378/5373) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)
- [So long, and thanks for all the fish?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49408) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [PSE Assessment Exam](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49621/5373) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)
- [Can you find the missing lad and the treasure?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49664/) by [Mithrandir](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25966/mithrandir)
- *add entries in the form `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [PSE Assessment Exam](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49621/5373) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio), with a score of **10** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [Where is Steven the Stegosaurus?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49341) by [suomynonA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30865) , with approximately **500** views during the fortnight.