# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #28: Liars

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is not the twenty-eighth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge not described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics neither suggested nor voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is not [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars) (not suggested by Jon Mark Perry), and will not span from the the **6th to the 19th of March**. During this period, we will neither compile the list of questions with this tag nor post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please don't go and [don't propose nor vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have no fun, and no happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*This is not a link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Answer (score 5):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[liars]%20created%3a2017-03-06..2017-03-19%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #28:**

- [You trolls, get out of my party!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49772) by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)
- [Who led the mutiny?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49849/33990) by [anonymous2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/33990/anonymous2)
- [Name the trolls](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49936/5044) by [Victor Stafusa](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5044/victor-stafusa)
- [Convoluted Logic Puzzles 101 and 102](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49983/) by [Mike Earnest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10615/)
- [The Lying Servers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50068) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/)
- *add entries in the form `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [You trolls, get out of my party!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49772), by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit), with a score of **23** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [You trolls, get out of my party!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49772), by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit), with approximately **5k** views during the fortnight.