# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #29: Retrograde Analysis

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the twenty-ninth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [retrograde-analysis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retrograde-analysis) (suggested by user24580), and will span from the the **21st of March to the 4th of April**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Comment: While this is not something I came up with, I came across a blog full of various (simple to an extent) retrograde analysis puzzles. Ranging from tic-tac-toe to dots-n-boxes. Maybe it'll provide some inspiration for puzzles outside of chess as many people seem to only tie this tag to chess based puzzles. https://joekisenwether.wordpress.com/non-chess-retrograde-analysis/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Kisenwether's Scrabble retro is stupendous. I seem to recall (I'm not at home now so I can't check) that I rechecked it with a word list which is still current, and it is still sound although there are more cases to check. (ISTR the new word APO is an issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[retrograde-analysis]%20created%3a2017-03-21..2017-04-04%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #29:**

- [Introducing: Sudoku-Janpu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50330/introducing-sudoku-janpu) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)
- [A retroanalysis problem in bridge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50597/a-retroanalysis-problem-in-bridge) by [Rosie F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22922/rosie-f)
- [The master programmer and the mystical reversal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50600/the-master-programmer-and-the-mystical-reversal) <sup>*</sup> by [KeyboardWielder](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20538/keyboardwielder)
- [Megan and the chess game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50615/megan-and-the-chess-game) by [Rosie F](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22922/rosie-f)
- [Let's continue our Monopoly game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50645/lets-continue-our-monopoly-game) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)

---

The **highest-voted** *and* the **most viewed** of these is [Let's continue our Monopoly game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50645/lets-continue-our-monopoly-game) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey), with a score of 18 and approximately 2000 views at the end of the fortnight.

---

<sup>* Note: KeyboardWielder's puzzle uses the tag in its more general sense, as discussed [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5867/definition-of-retrograde-analysis).</sup>