# EXTENDED: Fortnightly Topic Challenge #30: Metapuzzles

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the thirtieth installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is [metapuzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzles) (suggested by [paramesis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35042/paramesis)), and will span from the the **11th of April to the 3rd of May**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**Please note: this topic challenge has been extended one week. Its prior deadline was the 25th of April.**

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure a fortnight is going to be enough to construct quality metapuzzles, maybe we should think of extending this challenge be a week or so?

Comment: @Emrakul So was the 3rd of May a typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmetapuzzles%5D+created%3A2017-04-11..2017-04-25+is%3Aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #30:**

- *add entries in the form `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*
- [Ode to the heroes, vanquisher of puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51065) by [stack reader](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30804)
- [I, for one, welcome our new](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51078/i-for-one-welcome-our-new) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)
- [Missing, 'till the very end](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51230/missing-till-the-very-end) by [boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)
- [Take note, this is my favorite thing](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51265/take-note-this-is-my-favorite-thing) by [awesomepi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/167/awesomepi)
- [Ruklo Town Adventure](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/ruklo-town-adventure) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [This puzzle's main portion is a piece of... cake?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51329/this-puzzles-main-portion-is-a-piece-of-cake) by [Sp3000](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/445/sp3000)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[This puzzle's main portion is a piece of... cake?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51329/this-puzzles-main-portion-is-a-piece-of-cake)*, with a score of *29* at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is *[I, for one, welcome our new](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51078/i-for-one-welcome-our-new)*, with approximately *1373* views during the fortnight.

Comment: I have deleted my entries, which are some members considered them as not metapuzzles.

Comment: I believe before it's over - these still need to be deemed proper metapuzzles or not because right now some of them are questioned for actually fitting the criteria.