# Should we extend the [metapuzzles] topic challenge?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

The [metapuzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzles) fortnightly topic challenge has been very successful. However, Beastly Gerbil brought up [a good point in the comments](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/fortnightly-topic-challenge-30-metapuzzles#comment13298_5889):

> I'm not sure a fortnight is going to be enough to construct quality metapuzzles, maybe we should think of extending this challenge be a week or so?

I don't see any issues with this proposal - this FTC has been very productive, and I'd love to see more metapuzzles. Plus, quality metas take time to craft, and some people might not be able to finish theirs in time for the FTC to be over.

<sup><sup>(And okay, maybe I have an ulterior motive in that *I'm* one of those people since I'm busy with finals.)</sup></sup>

What do you all think? Is it worth it to extend the "deadline"?

Comment: woo, a whole post about me ;)

Answer (score 10):

## Yes

This topic has been bringing out a several puzzles that exemplify what this site is about, and many users have been introduced to a new genre of puzzles that they haven't heard about.

However, I propose that we should simultaneously launch the next topic challenge (either steganography again or non-planar mazes), especially since a lot of newer users aren't able to put in the time/effort required to create a successful [metapuzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzles).

As for the length, I think a 1-week extension should be enough, as otherwise the challenge will seem to drag on.

---

There is a problem with this involving setting a precedent for future Fortnightly Topic Challenges. We would have to have some criteria to extend a Fortnightly Topic Challenge.

Would a meta post of this sort with an answer in favour of the extension, which has ≥ +10 score be enough? (You can vote in comments and also add your own proposal, the comment with the highest score will be implemented.)

Comment: Yes, a meta post and an answer like this with at least +10 score is enough.

Comment: No, a meta post and an answer like this with at least +10 score is not enough/too much, though no alternative solution is proposed.

Comment: I agree with this post, except possibly the part of launching the next challenge simultaneously.

Comment: A meta post with a sub-meta vote via comments.... how meta

Comment: @DavidStarkey About a meta post on metapuzzles, too!