# What is the current fortnightly topic challenge?

Tags: support, topic-challenge

Sorry if I'm being a bit ignorant, but what is the current fortnightly topic challenge? According to [the topic discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be-with-updates), the metapuzzle thing ends on May 3rd. In fact, [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/extended-fortnightly-topic-challenge-30-metapuzzles) also suggests that the [metapuzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metapuzzles) topic has also ended. Has it?

Comment: There isn't one. Basically, we're all lazy.

Comment: I just wonder if we can have more than 1 fortnightly topic challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[EXTENDED: Fortnightly Topic Challenge #30: Metapuzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/extended-fortnightly-topic-challenge-30-metapuzzles)** ended May 3.
No new Fortnightly Topic Challenge has formally begun since then — perhaps due to the current election, but also perhaps because none of the regular FTC maintainers have had occasion to score the challenge just ended or to post the new topic.

I think Lukas Rotter had built some automation to automatically add FTC entries to the relevant page (and maybe to tally up results), but as they are no longer active here I think much of the FTC work is in search of a new champion or two.

Comment: Wait a sec, what do you mean by 'in search of a new champion or two'?

Comment: Volunteers to manage the FTCs

Comment: @Rubio [I don't mind](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5973/2071)