# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #31: Steganography (round 2)

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is th*e* thirty-first installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fort*n*ight's topic is [steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography) (suggested by Mithrandir), and will span from the the **5th of *J*une to the 18th of June**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and p*o*st it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happ*y* puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

Comment: Does this question count as a [steganography] puzzle? If so, it should be listed in the answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsteganography%5D+created%3A2017-06-05..2017-06-18+is%3Aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #31:**

- [Where am I waving to?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52421/where-am-i-waving-to) by [Jan Ivan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34043/jan-ivan)
- [Peculiar headlines](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52433/peculiar-headlines) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [ELECTRONIC SURVEILLANCE REPORT 1706](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52440/electronic-surveillance-report-1706) by [Rubio](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio)
- [Could Hobbs Bait a Different Philosopher?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52441/could-hobbs-bait-a-different-philosopher) by [Hugh Meyers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18924/hugh-meyers)
- [How I see things in real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52463/5373) by [Jan Ivan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34043/jan-ivan)
- [Your Dream Job Awaits](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52473/your-dream-job-awaits) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [A very unique Web Question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52480/5373) by [shays](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37405/shays)
- [Somebody broke into my house](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52541/18250) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil)
- [The answer is right here silly](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52562/18250) by [n_palum](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34679/n-palum)
- [Messages hidden in the "visit every square once" puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52575/52576)
  by [Jamal Senjaya](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28756)
- *add entries in the form `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[Messages hidden in the "visit every square once" puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52575/messages-hidden-in-the-visit-every-square-once-puzzle)*, with a score of *24* at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is *[Messages hidden in the "visit every square once" puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52575/messages-hidden-in-the-visit-every-square-once-puzzle)*, with approximately *2,404* views during the fortnight.

Comment: Does [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52465/5373) count, or should we only list actual puzzles and not questions?

Comment: @randal'thor I don't see a problem with including it. Probably a question worth it's own meta post though. After all, asking a "how to solve [current challenge]" every fortnight could be undesirable.