# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #32: Grid Deduction Hybrids

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the thirty-first installment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is hybrids of [grid-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) (suggested by paramesis), and will span from the the **19th of June to the 2nd of July**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***
For those that cannot see the deleted answer suggestion, here is how the grid deduction hybrid was described:

> In these, you combine multiple grid deduction puzzle types.  I've seen a few posted here involving Sudoku:
>
> [Revenge of the Cryptic Crossword Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49560/revenge-of-the-cryptic-crossword-sudoku)
>   [Empty sudoku puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47987/empty-sudoku-puzzle)
>   [Introducing Domidoku!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/introducing-domidoku)
>   [Sudoku embedded in a Kakuro](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50283/sudoku-embedded-in-a-kakuro)
>
> Here are several more examples:
>
> [Yajilin Battleships](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2017/03/yajilin-battleships-serkan-yurekli/)
>   [Cave Battle](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2017/02/cave-battle-roger-barkan/)
>   [Fillomino Kropki](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/12/fillomino-kropki-prasanna-seshadri/)
>   [Kropki Loop](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/12/kropki-loop-prasanna-seshadri/)
>   [Battleships Myopia](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/12/battleships-myopia-prasanna-seshadri/)
>   [Pentominous Star Battle](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/09/pentominous-star-battle-grant-fikes/)
>   [Yajilin Myopia](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/08/yajilin-myopia-by-murat-can-tonta/)
>   [Japanese Latin Sums](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/09/japaneselatin-sums-serkan-yurekli/)
>   [Masyu Battleships](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/08/masyu-battleships-by-walker-anderson/)
>   [Easy As Kakuro](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2016/07/easy-as-kakuro-by-serkan-yurekli/)

Due to the nature of this challenge, please add your own questions to the list below.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=38222710#38222710

Comment: Will any puzzle that is a grid to be deduced qualify or does it need to be a hybrid of a known grid puzzle type?

Comment: @Forklift the request specifically mentioned hybrids.  It's not yet deleted, so you can see it [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5871/2071)

Comment: Ah, ok. Looks like hybrids of known puzzles. Thanks.

Comment: Is it alright to have a grid-deduction puzzle that has only one type, but is unconventional in another way?

Comment: @boboquack I would think that would be fine

Comment: Hi David, thanks for maintaining the FTC posts! If you don't mind, my bot ([RottersSlave](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/32660/rottersslave)) could take over that task again starting from 2nd of July.

Comment: @LukasRotter That's fine by me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**List of [all grid-deduction questions published](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgrid-deduction%5D+created%3A2017-06-19..2017-07-02+is%3Aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #32:**

- [A Knight's Kuromasu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52796/a-knights-kuromasu) by [David Starkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2071/david-starkey)
- [Introducing: Jormungand](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52828/introducing-jormungand) by [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5297/)
- [Parallelisation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52858) by [Wen1now](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32642)
- [Desert Irrigation Project](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52896/desert-irrigation-project) by [paramesis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35042)
- [The Ludicrous Loop: over a thousand cells of circular logic!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52899/the-ludicrous-loop-over-a-thousand-cells-of-circular-logic) by [TheGreatEscaper](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32596/thegreatescaper)
- [Oh no, it's another safe!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/52901/5840) by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)
- [I am an island (ysaujdiolkiun)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53009) by [paramesis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35042)
- [Tetromino Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53062) by [Mike Q](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30304)
- [My God, it's full of stars!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53086) by [paramesis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35042)
- *add entries in the form `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[The Ludicrous Loop: over a thousand cells of circular logic!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52899/the-ludicrous-loop-over-a-thousand-cells-of-circular-logic)*, with a score of *40* at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is *[The Ludicrous Loop: over a thousand cells of circular logic!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52899/the-ludicrous-loop-over-a-thousand-cells-of-circular-logic)*, with approximately *817* views during the fortnight.

Comment: Woah, this is going to be pretty close