# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #33: Surface Geometry Mazes

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the thirty-third instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is surface geometry [mazes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mazes)(suggested by [Typhon](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21905)), and will span from the the **3rd of July to the 16th of July**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***

For those that cannot see the deleted answer suggestion, here is how the surface geometry maze was described:

> How about one where we have surface geometry mazes? I don't know the exact tags, but the challenge could be mazes that are on non-planar surfaces and/or involve transforming from one surface to another. For instance, maybe a maze on a tube where you can unroll the tube into a plane, and then roll it into a tube with the other sides. Granted, that's just an idea. We could also have hyperbolic, spherical, recursive, etc. So long as they involve non-planar surfaces they would apply.

Comment: I am honored to have my suggestion selected. I hope everyone has fun doing it! Funny how I went to being confused about my post being deleted to realizing it was deleted due to acceptance. :-D

Comment: I am not 100% on what this actually means, and I suggest you or someone else adds some examples like for the previous FTC. Based on the description, would [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52828/introducing-jormungand) be a good example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**List of [all questions published](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[mazes]%20created%3a2017-7-3..2017-7-16%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #33:**

- [Every Fourth Wormhole](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53145) by [paramesis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35042)
- [Nodes & Tunnels](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53435) by [BreakingMyself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37821)
- [More Nodes & Tunnels - The Tower](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53463) by [BreakingMyself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37821)
- [My grandfather left me something odd in his will](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53537/my-grandfather-left-me-something-odd-in-his-will) by [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil)

---

The **highest-voted** of these is [Every Fourth Wormhole](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53145) by [paramesis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35042), with a score of **26** at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is [Every Fourth Wormhole](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53145) by [paramesis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/35042), with approximately **600** views during the fortnight.