# Fortnightly Topic Challenge #34: Safes and Locks

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

This is the thirty-fourth instalment of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge described [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges), with topics suggested and voted on [here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be). This fortnight's topic is safes and [locks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locks)(suggested by [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840)), and will span from the the **31st of July to the 13th of August**. During this period, we will compile the list of questions with this tag and post it as an answer to this question.

**In the meantime, please go and [propose and vote on future challenges!](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/what-should-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges-be)**

Everyone have fun, and happy puzzling!

---

<sub>*Link to [other](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20title%3a"Fortnightly%20Topic%20Challenge%20%23) Fortnightly Topic Challenges.*</sub>

***NOTE***

For those that cannot see the deleted answer suggestion, here is how it was described:

> How about [safes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safes) or [locks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locks)?  (Maybe a better tag name would be required, but I can't think of one right now.) 
> These would be all sorts of puzzles which could be used in role-playing-games or similar as 'obstacles' for the players. While *any* puzzle might be framed to be a 'safes & locks' puzzle, I'm really thinking of puzzles which are simple and not too multi-layered, which have a simple *visual* representation, and which could be used 'out of the box'...
> Edit: Not patient enough to wait for the challenge to be selected one day... so I posted an [example puzzle](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) right away :c)

Comment: Of course BmyGuest suggested this :P

Answer (score 3):

**List of [all questions published](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[locks]%20created%3a2017-7-31..2017-8-13%20is%3aquestion) as part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge #34:**

- [Numbers hidden in fantasy story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53990) by [Morgan G](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12914)
- ...
- *add entries in the form `https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID>` by `[username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[TBD]*, with a score of *[TBD]* at the end of the fortnight.

The **most viewed** is *[TBD]*, with approximately *[TBD]* views during the fortnight.